# .htaccess remove trailing slash in url except when folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a basic URL rewrite that works well, except when navigating to **folders**:

When a user navigates to any folder `mydomain.com/folder/`he is redirected to `mydomain.com/folder?pl1=css`, causing an infinite redirect loop.

I've tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ -d` just above the rule that redirects pages to their versions without trailing slashes. This solves the infinite loop problem, but breaks the redirecting to the pages without trailing slashes (which I would like to keep for SEO reasons: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.be/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

My question:

- How to handle folders correclty => show default page (/folder/index.html; if it exists) within the folder when navigating to `mydomain.com/folder`or `mydomain.com/folder/`(without appending variables to url)
- For extra brownie points: how to optimize the second part of the rewrite, so as not to use 6 lines of code :-)

This is my code:

```
# Start the rewrite engine
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
# Rule below fixes loop, but breaks redirection
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ -d

# Handle my GET variables
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$                                                                                            index.php?pl1=$1                                        [L] 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$                                                                           index.php?pl1=$1&pl2=$2                                 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$                                                          index.php?pl1=$1&pl2=$2&pl3=$3                          [L] 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$                                         index.php?pl1=$1&pl2=$2&pl3=$3&pl4=$4                   [L] 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$                        index.php?pl1=$1&pl2=$2&pl3=$3&pl4=$4&pl5=$5            [L] 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$       index.php?pl1=$1&pl2=$2&pl3=$3&pl4=$4&pl5=$5&pl6=$6     [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this "*...except when navigating to folders...*" means to **existing** folders, you can try adding the next 3 lines before the comment `# Remove trailing slash`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .*   - [L]
```

It is possible to reduce the rules to a single one, as long as there is no problem having empty *keys* (`pl6=`). Like this:

```
# Handle my GET variables
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?/?  index.php?pl1=$1&pl2=$2&pl3=$3&pl4=$4&pl5=$5&pl6=$6  [L,NC]
```

Makes all parameters optional, except the first one.

Comment: Thanks so muchfor your answer! 

If I implement the first part of your answer I get the desired effect, except that it redirects to ´/folder/?pl1=folder´. Any ideas?

The second part of your answer does not seem to work, as it generates 404 errors in my system. Also, I do mind to have empty keys.

Comment: "*Also, I do mind to have empty keys*". Then, you need a rule for each parameter, as it is in your question.

Comment: "*...redirects to ´/folder/?pl1=folder*" I guess it is redirected by another rule that adds the query. You may try deleting `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]` in my answer so it doesn't look for files. But not sure of the result. Make sure the browser's cache is cleared before any test.

Comment: The winner takes it all! You solved my question. Thank you for answering every aspect of my question in such a clear and useful fashion! Good call on clearing cache aswel.

Comment: Sure did. I guess I will keep my uncool 6 lines of code for my variable rewrites though ;-)